# Accessing Transient field of Entity through Service

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Currently, I am learning Spring Boot. I got trouble with accessing the @Transient variable of Entity class from my @Service class.

Actually, I want to calculate the popularity of the book in my Service and want to assign it to a specific book.

```
    @Transient
    private Double popularity;
```

Any tips on solving this problem.
Let me know if you need more information.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: How do you initialise this `popularity` ? Think about when to calculate and set this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transient properties are properties that do not have an appropriate column in the database table. But of course, they should have getters and setters, as any other property.
So after you calculate the popularity, just simply use the setter (setPopularity) as for any other class property.

Comment: But for it I have to create an instance of Entity class. Is it will be ok having one instance in Service class?